# Show that $\left|\inf_{x\in A} f(x)-\inf_{x\in A} g(x)\right| \leq \sup_{x\in A} |f(x)-g(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $f,g:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be convex functions defined on a convex subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$. How can I prove the following inequality:

$$\left|\inf_{x\in A} f(x)-\inf_{x\in A} g(x)\right| \leq \sup_{x\in A} |f(x)-g(x)| \text{ ?}$$

My plan was to look first at the case where $\inf_{x\in A} f(x)$ and $\inf_{x\in A} g(x)$ are attained, but even this case gives me trouble.

Any help on this is very appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897795/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really have much to do with convexity. I will assume the functions are bounded below.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and start with a point $x_0 \in A$ where
$$g(x_0) < \inf_{x \in A} g(x) + \epsilon.$$ Then $$\inf_{x \in A} f(x) \le f(x_0) \le |f(x_0) - g(x_0)| + g(x_0) < \sup_{x \in A} |f(x) - g(x)| + \inf_{x \in A} g(x) + \epsilon$$ This gets you to
$$\inf_{x \in A} f(x) - \inf_{x \in A} g(x) < \sup_{x \in A} |f(x) - g(x)| + \epsilon$$ but with $x_0$ no longer in the picture you can let $\epsilon \to 0^+$ to discover
$$\inf_{x \in A} f(x) - \inf_{x \in A} g(x) \le \sup_{x \in A} |f(x) - g(x)|.$$

Now do the same thing starting with $f$ rather than $g$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! So only the hypothesis $f,g$ bounded below is necessary here? So that $ \sup_{x\in A} |f(x)-g(x)|$ could be $\infty$? In this case the inequality would be strict.

Comment: It isn't really necessary if only one of $f$ or $g$ is unbounded below. In that case the inequality simply reads $\infty \le \infty$. On the other hand if they are both unbounded below the left-hand side will read $|-\infty - (-\infty)|$ which isn't meaningful regardless of the value of the right-hand side.

Comment: I see, but the inequality can be of the form $c<\infty$ with $c\in \mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: Of course. Consider $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^4$.

Answer (score 2):

In the case where the two infima are attained, then they are both attained either at the same point in the domain, or at two different points.

In the former case you have
\begin{align}
& \left| \inf_{x\,\in\,A} f(x) - \inf_{x\,\in\,A} g(x) \right| \\[8pt]
= {} & |f(x_0)-g(x_0)| \\
& \text{where $x_0$ is the point where the infima are attained} \\[8pt]
\le {} & \sup_{x\,\in\,A}|f(x)-g(x)|.
\end{align}
In the other case you have
\begin{align}
& \left| \inf_{x\,\in\,A} f(x) - \inf_{x\,\in\,A} g(x) \right| \\[8pt]
= {} & |f(x_0)-g(x_1)| \\
& \text{where $x_0,x_1$ are the points where} \\
& \text{the respective infima are attained.} \\ & \text{No generality is lost be assuming} \\
& f(x_0)\le g(x_1). \text{ Then we have:} \\[8pt]
\le {} & |f(x_0)-g(x_0)| \\[8pt]
\le {} & \sup_{x\,\in\,A}|f(x)-g(x)|.
\end{align}